# find CK of Trapezoid, K is a point

Tags: geometry

Let Trapezoid ABCD with bases BC and AD. BC=8, AD=18, AC=10, BD=24.
K is a point on AD such that AK = 13.

Please, help me find the CK.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? It would help if you told us where exactly you have trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the coordinates of B be $(x,h).$ Then the coordinates of of $C,D, K$ are respectively $ (x+8,h),(18,0),(13,0):$

$$ BD^2= 24^2 =(18-x)^2 + h^2 $$

$$ AC^2= (8+x)^2 + h^2 = 10^2$$

Subtract and transpose

$$ x^2 + h^2 -36 x = 252, \tag{1}$$

similarly

$$ x^2 + h^2 +16 x = 36  \tag{2}$$

Solving for $x,h$

$$ -x= \frac{54}{13}, \; h= \frac {120}{13} \tag {3}$$

$$ CK = \sqrt{ (50/13-13)^2 +(120/13)^2  } \tag{4} = 13. $$